# What does out in dotnet publish mean?

Tags: .net, docker, output, dotnet-publish

In this article I've found a way to speed up docker build command

https://www.softwaredeveloper.blog/optimize-building-net-core-docker-image

This command caches nuget dependencies

`RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out`

I just can't catch what does **out** mean ,it should be a path , but running such command fails , because

`COPY --from=publish out .`

does not work.How can i use this in my docker file?

Answer (score 2):

It does mean that it publishes the built project to the `out` directory. But it's relative to the current working directory which may be what's causing your issue.

If you take this Dockerfile, then we first make an `/app` directory. So when we publish to `out`, the full path is `/app/out`.

So when we build the runtime image, we can copy from `/app/out` in the build image and put it somewhere else. Here I've put it in `/app`.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 as build
WORKDIR /app
RUN dotnet new webapp
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 as runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/app/app.dll"]
```